# How to get around building Boost.Iostreams separatly with zip (gz) support on Windows?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, boost, zlib, boost-iostreams

I want to compile such [simple code](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/libs/iostreams/doc/classes/gzip.html):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

#include <zlib.h>

#include <boost/iostreams/filtering_streambuf.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/copy.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/filter/gzip.hpp>

int main()
{
    std::string hello =  "Hello world";

    std::ofstream zip_png_file( "hello.gz",  std::ofstream::binary);
    boost::iostreams::filtering_streambuf< boost::iostreams::input> in;
    in.push( boost::iostreams::gzip_decompressor());
    in.push(hello);
    boost::iostreams::copy(in, zip_png_file);

    std::cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

I have compioled Boost with:

```
-j4 --prefix="C:\Program Files\Boost" --without-mpi --without-python link=static runtime-link=static install
```

By that time I had no **zlib** or **bzip2** installed in my system. Now I staticly compiled zlib and bzib2 into `"C:\Program Files\zlib"` and `"C:\Program Files\bzip2"`  (with `lib` and `include` folders in tham)

I created simple VS2010 project and statically linked boost, linked zip added include folders. but instead of compiling I got 5 errors:

```
Error   5   error C1903: unable to recover from previous error(s); stopping compilation c:\program files (x86)\boost-1.47.0\include\boost\iostreams\traits.hpp  242
Error   1   error C2039: 'category' : is not a member of 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>' c:\program files (x86)\boost-1.47.0\include\boost\iostreams\traits.hpp  
Error   2   error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'type'    c:\program files (x86)\boost-1.47.0\include\boost\iostreams\traits.hpp  242
Error   4   error C2208: 'boost::type' : no members defined using this type c:\program files (x86)\boost-1.47.0\include\boost\iostreams\traits.hpp  242
Error   3   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   c:\program files (x86)\boost-1.47.0\include\boost\iostreams\traits.hpp  242
```

So I wonder can zlib be connected to boost Iostreams after all boost was compiled or I have to rebuild it], if yes what arguments shall I add to mine to get 100% statically linked normal Boost + Boost.Iostreams (with zlib support)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, the code would not compile even on a properly configured system: it attempts to use a string (not a stream) as the source, and it attempts to apply `gzip_decompressor` to a plain ASCII string.

The following code compiles and runs on Visual Studio 2010 SP1 with boost installed by the [BoostPro](http://www.boostpro.com/download/) installer with all default options, no other libraries installed.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/iostreams/filtering_streambuf.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/copy.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/filter/gzip.hpp>
int main()
{
    std::string hello = "Hello world";
    std::istringstream src(hello);

    boost::iostreams::filtering_streambuf< boost::iostreams::input> in;
    in.push(boost::iostreams::gzip_compressor());
    in.push(src);

    std::ofstream zip_png_file( "hello.gz",  std::ofstream::binary);
    boost::iostreams::copy(in, zip_png_file);
}
```